# Java RestFull WebService: JAX-RS implementation with Jersey 2.3.1 libraries

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jboss6.x

I am trying to run a simple "Hallo World" application Jersey 2.3.1 REST service on JBoss jboss-eap-6.1 AS. In web.xml i have disabled restEasy library. During deployment i am getting the error:

> JBWEB000289: Servlet
>   com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication threw load()
>   exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

In POM i put these dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my web.xml with restEasy tags disabling:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my resource config java class:

```
package com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
public class MyApplication extends  ResourceConfig {   

     public MyApplication() {
            packages("com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources");
          //super(HelloWorldResource.class);

     }
}
```

Someone have any idea to solve it?
thanks in advance,
Roberto

Comment: Probably you want to refrain from using `com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources` as the package for your own files... `com.sun` may not be yours... just a guess.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually means you are having two different versions of the class on your classpath. As the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class does have the `getProperties()` method in its JAX-RS 2 version, but not in JAX-RS 1.x, I would guess that somehow you are combining the old 1.x Jersey (or old REST api) with the current (2.3.1) one.

Also the package you are working in (`com.sun.jersey` - the 'old' Jersey package) points a bit towards this direction (although just placing your code into that package itself cannot cause the mentioned problem), you obviously started with the Jersey 1.x example as a base (there are samples in Jersey 2 as well, see [helloworld-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-webapp) on Jersey GitHub).

Is it possible, that restEasy (also definitely containing the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class) is not completely switched off and somehow defaults to JAX-RS 1.x version?

I would start with inspecting your pom file, look at the effective pom (if your project descriptor has some parent) and check carefully what is on your classpath - I believe there is a 1.x version of `javax.ws.rs-api` somewhere. Also try to clean all the compiled stuff and rebuild from scratch.

Speaking of dependencies, if your list is exhaustive (regarding Jersey), you will most likely have to add `jersey-common` (2.3.1) dependency, as already during the initialization, the `ResourceConfig.packages()` method calls the `PackageScanner` constructor, which contains call to `ReflectionHelper` - and this is not a part of the server jar any more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your interest,i tried to add maven dependency jersey-common (2.3.1) as you suggest,also i tried to disable RESTeasy removing the lines: <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/> and <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/> in either configuration file: <JBoss_Home>/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml and <JBoss_AS_7_Home>/domain/configuration/domain.xml but nothing has canched...probably as you suggest, jboss dont switch off RESTeasy...

Comment: For those who had problems by using `com.sun.jersey`, look at `org.glassfish.jersey` for Jersey 2.x packages.

Comment: If using gradle, you may enter this section:     configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            //This solves the issue with different gradle package names for the same set of classes implementing (different versions of) JSR-311.
            substitute module('javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api') with module('javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1')
        }
    }

Answer (score 18):

I faced same problem recently. I thought share my steps for you. As the other answers state, the problem is mainly because of having two different versions of the same class on your classpath. So when you add maven dependencies in your pom be careful.

These kind of problems are normally called as **Jar Hell**. You can use **[jhades](http://jhades.org/)** API for investigate the classes overlap one another. Here is the simple steps i have followed.

**Add jhades dependency into your pom.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jhades</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhades</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Show the report**

Call `new JHades().overlappingJarsReport();` in your `main` method, it will output to stdout.

*Sample Output:*

```
file:/Users/justin/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar overlaps with
file:/Users/justin/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar - total overlapping classes: 55 - same classloader ! This is an ERROR!
```

**Remove one of overlap maven dependency in your pom.**

Also you can use another approach like maven's [dependency exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Source: [Blog post on jhades](https://dzone.com/articles/jar-hell-and-back)

Hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Just to build on this, the next step it run run a dependency tree. Use . mvn dependency:tree > deps.txt. Then search the text file for the jar that was flagged by Jhades.

Comment: Hell indeed. Thanks for this suggestion! jhades

Comment: Hi I have same problem. I am using Jersey2.22.2 and I don't have any other jar file in my class path other that Jersey. I am getting the same error. I ran the Jhades the report does not say anything about Jersey multiple classes. I am using apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4 server. any suggestions?

Comment: @Philip PJ normally this will happens due to when dependencies are overlap each other.in your situation there would be also.if this approach doesn't help you.you have to find a another approach.I am sorry i amnot much familiar with apache tomee.maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780860/maven-junit-openejb-applicationcomposer-leads-to-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror. if you fix your issue please post ur answer here then it will help for some one.

Comment: also try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662277/tomee-spring-jax-rs-nosuchmethoderror-jar-conflict

Comment: I configured Glassfish and it is running fine. I am happy with Glassfish to test my REST web services. Thanks for the support

Comment: jhades.org is out of date

Answer (score 14):

Just got this working on JBoss EAP 6.1.1 - Jersey 2.3.1.

The usual things don't seem to work/are not enough on their own:

- disabling the jaxrs-subsystem in standalone.xml/domain.xml
- or, excluding the jax-rs modules in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Additionaly you need to disable the loading of the jax-rs 1.1 API completely by modifying module.xml in
jboss-eap-6.1/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/module.xml like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="javax.ws.rs.api">
<resources>
    <!-- Disable the next line -->
    <!-- resource-root path="jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar"/ -->
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" services="export"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Please note that this will disable the jax-rs implementation of JBoss (RestEasy) for all other applications as well (as does disabling the jaxrs subsystem in standalone/domain.xml).

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, the path was little different to module.xml. It was like, `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\javax\ws\rs\api\main\module.xml`

Comment: This solution also solved my problem when trying to call a external rest service so the client side is running on JBoss EAP 6.4 (and packed on a EAR file - no web application)

Comment: Is there any way without modifying module.xml ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a Jersey version conflict problem. I had the same problem. Here is how it is resolved:

1. See your package dependencies "mvn dependency:tree"
2. If there is a library dependency that depends on an old Jersey version, you could add an exclusions section in the dependency tag for that library in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Using mvn dependency:tree (thanks for suggestion above) I was able to identify that the culprit (in my case) was: javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1
Removing this dependency solved my problem.