# TOMEE + Spring + JAX-RS (NoSuchMethodError) jar conflict

Tags: spring, tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy, apache-tomee

I am trying to run my application in TomEE server, After much hassles I am able to run the application.

However for some reason I am getting some sort of jar conflict for resteasy and hence an error as below whenever a resteasy resource class is being called from application

```
Jun 05, 2015 5:57:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [resteasy-servlet] in context with path [/MyApplicationName] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:186)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I verified the BuiltResponse class which extends the Response class in resteasy jar and it seems fine that it includes the method. I tried extracting many of other jars so that it provides a conflict. Below is part of my POM dealing with resteasy

```
<!-- Resteasy rest services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am suspecting that it could be some jar which is in tomEE lib folder which is causing conflict but couldn't find any.

**Question 1** : If that's the case is there a way in TomEE/Tomcat so that we can force application to pick up the jar in application WEB-INF/lib folder and not server lib folder. Just like in weblogic we can update weblogic-application.xml by putting the jar path in prefer-application-package tag.

**Question 2** : All the searching points me that it's a jar conflict issue. But how come same jar structure works in weblogic or other server if it's an internal jar conflict of application? Does some server has better application jar managing structure than others?

Comment: try to put `openejb.api.javax.ws.rs.Path.validation=false` into tomee/conf/system.properties

Comment: Hey @HowardWang Thanks, I tried that but it didn't help. Still gets the same exception.

Comment: Why are you using resteasy on TomEE?? It bundles CXF.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Tomee lib has another jar file "javaee-api-6.0-6.jar" which also has Response class with same namespace, so it is conflicting with class name in jax-rs jar. Jax-rs is getting Tomee lib jar's Response class which doesnt have required method.

Comment: How do we tell the app to load from web-inf/lib first?

Answer (score 0):

```
Suggesting 3 solutions to your problem.All 3 solutions are working for me.Let me know if it works for you.
```

1) Use tomcat server with your same pom.xml

2) Modify pom.xml. Use tomee server.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

3) Use jersey jax-rs implementation. Use tomee server.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```