# Deploying WAR file on TOMCAT throws error only for REST API where APPLICATION_JSON used

Tags: java, api, rest, tomcat, internal-server-error

I am using netbeans to create my project and my code runs fine on Localhost . I create a war file and deploy on tomcat 7 and 8 , and it throws Internal server Error 500 . A little changes in code after a day of problem solving got us here to a point where our rest api where we use Mediatype.Application_json , it crashes gives the Internal server error .

When a string is passed using Mediatype.TEXT_HTML , we dont have an issue .

Unfortunately POST for rest api only taken in JSON and I am desperately trying to find someone who can solve this

Please help

Comment: can you please post the error stack trace?

Comment: exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.sprintler.services.ApplicationConfig threw exception
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)

Comment: root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)

Comment: Unable to add more data in One post due to character restrictions but this is  the top few lines of EXCEPTION and ROOT CAUSE

Comment: ^ @bezzerk: please transfer the code in comments into your question. There are formatting tools that will make it much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two versions of the JAX-RS jars on the classpath. Or you have an unwanted `jsr311-api` jar on your classpath.
See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19261016/868975).

Answer (score 0):

I made sure all the versions etc of all JAX jars were not duplicated . And since I was on a deadline , I just used Maven in my project and works like a charm