# Code works on dev server, fails to start on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, objectify, jsr311

Till recently my code had been working fine, on GAE and on dev server. Then recently I uploaded a new version and that doesn't work at all on the server, works just fine on my local machine (dev server). The older version continues to work on the server.

Every time the I hit any URL of the newer version, the following stracktrace is found in the logs:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the most relevant dependency that I could find (it's in a utility library that I am using in my project):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and true enough, the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class in it doesn't contain a `getProperties()` method.

Now the question is, why/how is this code working on the dev server?

I haven't made any recent changes that affect this library or even the general layout and working of the code (just added some functionality to existing code), so what is causing this issue?

Was using version 1.9.32 of GAE Java SDK and recently upgraded to 1.9.34 -- problem happened after that (however, switching back to 1.9.32 didn't help). Cloud Platform console indicates SDK version 1.9.35.

In desperation I tried:

- clean & rebuild (also on the library project depends on),
- delete newer versions on GAE & re-upload
- re-upload code with a different version number

Versions from `pom.xml`:

```
<commons.codec.version>1.10</commons.codec.version>
<commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
<commons.lang3.version>3.4</commons.lang3.version>
<commons.validator.version>1.5.0</commons.validator.version>
<freemarker.version>2.3.20</freemarker.version>
<google.http.client.version>1.21.0</google.http.client.version>
<guava.version>19.0</guava.version>
<guice.servlet.version>4.0</guice.servlet.version>
<guice.version>4.0</guice.version>
<jackson.version>2.7.0</jackson.version>
<jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>
<joda.money.version>0.10.0</joda.money.version>
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
<lombok.version>1.16.6</lombok.version>
<objectify.version>5.1.9</objectify.version>
<stripe.version>1.38.0</stripe.version>

<appengine.version>1.9.32</appengine.version>
<gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.88.v20151125</gcloud.plugin.version>
<resources.plugin.version>2.7</resources.plugin.version>
```

(might have missed 1 or 2)

Comment: The fact that you are using `<jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>` and have `jsr311` is a problem. Jersey 2 using JAX-RS 2.0, which has imcompatibilities with jsr311. How is it working in the dev? Maybe difference in class loading. JAX-RS 2.0 and jsr311 both the Application class, but JAX-2.0 it is a newer version, which _does_ have the getProperties method. Unfortunately, when you see this error, that means that the Application class of the jsr311 is the one getting classloaded, and not the JAX-RS 2.0 version. Get rid of the jsr311 and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I had realized from reading [Java RestFull WebService: JAX-RS implementation with Jersey 2.3.1 libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19261016/91933) and was changing that when your comment popped up :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

where `${jersey.version}` is set to `2.5.1`. No idea how this had been working so far...

Realized this potential issue as I was reading [Java RestFull WebService: JAX-RS implementation with Jersey 2.3.1 libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19261016/91933) and that is also when the comment by @peeskillet poppped up.