# How to deploy REST web service to AWS?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, amazon-web-services

**What is need to be done?**

Deploy web application with web service(REST) on AWS. (Tomcat server)

**What I have done?**

Build web application with REST web service. Tested locally successfully.

**Problem**

Now when I deploy it to the AWS using elastic beanstalk giving **404 error.**

**My Web Service code**

```
@Path("/abc")
public class registerService {
    @POST
    @Path("/crunchifyService")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response crunchifyREST(InputStream incomingData) {
        StringBuilder crunchifyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                crunchifyBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
        }
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + crunchifyBuilder.toString());

        User userObject = new Gson().fromJson(crunchifyBuilder.toString(), User.class);
        System.out.println("JSon object: " + userObject.getSurname());
        int status = RegisterDao.register(userObject);
        if(status == 1)
        {



        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed again");

        }

        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(crunchifyBuilder.toString()).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/verify")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response verifyRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {
        String result = "CrunchifyRESTService Successfully started..";

        // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }


     @GET
       @Path("/users")
       @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       public Response getUsers(){
          return Response.status(200).entity("Done").build();
       }
}
```

REST client code

```
<%

 String json = new Gson().toJson(u);
System.out.println(json);

try {
  URL url = new URL("http://storageserver-env.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/MyApplicationName/api/abc/crunchifyService");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    OutputStreamWriter out1 = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out1.write(json);
    out1.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    while (in.readLine() != null) {
    }
    System.out.println("\nCrunchify REST Service Invoked Successfully..");
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nError while calling Crunchify REST Service");
    System.out.println(e);
}

%>
```

My server log says

> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2016:13:38:05 +0000] "POST /SecureStorage/api/abc/crunchifyService HTTP/1.1" 404 1070
>
> **

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SecureStorage</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
    createTable.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>registration</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Check your server log to see why the deployment is failing

Comment: @MarkB It simply says this "127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2016:13:38:05 +0000] "POST /SecureStorage/api/abc/crunchifyService HTTP/1.1" 404 1070"

Comment: That's your access log, not your deployment log

Comment: @MarkB Linked my log file

Comment: Dude... you need to delete that, it has your AWS keys in it.

Comment: You also need to go delete those AWS keys now and create new ones.

Comment: Look at all the exceptions in your `/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2016-04-09.log` I feel like you are wasting my time and everyone else's on this site by not looking at your log files and finding those exceptions yourself.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for everything

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the lesson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no difference between deploying web application or web service on AWS.**

You will get nice tutorial on aws website about how to deploy web application.

**What was my problem?**

After calling from rest client , it was giving me 404 error.

**How it was solved?**.

After instructions in above comments section , I found in my log.

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate
>   exception for servlet Application  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

This was a actual problem. This exception occurs when having two different versions of the class on your classpath. After this I deleted my extra overlapping jar. 
[More info about above exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225618/java-restfull-webservice-jax-rs-implementation-with-jersey-2-3-1-libraries)

**Another problem** 
After above improvement It was expected everything will  work fine , but still there 404 error code on service call from rest client.

**Solution**

My client used url in the following format.

> "http://storageserver-env.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/MyApplicationName/api/abc/crunchifyService"

*URLGivenByAWSWhereWebAppIsDepoyed/MyApplicationName/ResourcePath*

Above url format was working on local address i.e.
**locahost:8080/MyApplicationName/ResourcePath**

But it was not working after deployment.

**I tried by removing name of MyApplicationName from above url and it worked.**

**Working format**

*URLGivenByAWSWhereWebAppIsDepoyed/ResourcePath*

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In my case I get a 204 response but the method "crunchifyREST" is not called . I tried to log the response but it is not hitting that method . Any idea what is the issue? There are no exceptions in the server log